# Please suggest an optimised Django update Query on Bulk Data

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

So, I have list of dictionaries like this

**dnc_info** `= [{'website': 'www.mdn.com', 'name':'shubham', 'company_name': 'mdn'}, {'website': 'google.com', 'name': 'ketan', 'company_name': 'google'}, {'website': 'http://microsoft.com', name:'somename', , 'company_name': 'microsoft'}, {'website': None, 'name':'somename2',, 'company_name': None}....] upto 10,000 dict`

Now, I have a DataBase(PostgreSQL) table which contains the following field:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+---------
| company_name |   website   |       email        | campaign_id | color_code |  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+--+
| google       | google.com  | shubham@google.com |          50 | #FFFFFF    |  |
| mdn          | www.mdn.com | some@mdn.com       |          50 | #FFFFFF    |  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+---------
```

up to 20,000 rows

Now what I want is to be able to update the color code field the above table from `dnc_info` on basis following conditions

**Condition 1:** Table's company name should match with `dnc_info` company name ignoring case sensitivity
**Condition 2:** **Only website's domain** from table should match with `dnc_info` website domain ignoring case senstivity
**Condition 3:** Table's email domain should match with `dnc_info` website's domain also ignoring case sensitivity.
**Condition 4:** Table's email should match `dnc_info` email also ignoring case sensitivity.

I'm able to create separate lists for every object key from `dnc_info` like this:

```
website = ['mdn.com', 'google.com', 'microsoft.com']
email = ['shubham@mdn.com', 'someone@google.com']
```

Please suggest an optimised model query based on the above conditions that will update the column `color_code` in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ORM, I had used `raw_query()` and it worked for me.